# Compare date time with date : less or equal not working as expected

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets I'm facing an unexpected behavior :

Cell 1 : 09/04/2021 10:33:19

Cell 2 : 08/04/2021

In countifs, filter, ifs functions, **Cell 1 >= Cell 2 return Cell 1 > Cell 2** or sometimes the opposite

Why >= / > and <= / < are not working when comparing Cell 1 and Cell 2 ?

Example :
[countifs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLuNa.png)

Comment: Please provide the actual address which contains the dates, and the actual formula you typed, like `COUNTIFS(A1:A2;A1>A2)`

Comment: @Luuk just edited my question with an example : output is 4 but expected is 2
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLuNa.png

Comment: `09/04/2021` in *Cell_D4* equates to `09/04/2021 0:00:00` & all the 4 instances in A2:A5 are **`>`** D4

Comment: @rockinfreakshow thanks ! then is it possible to ignore the time during the comparaison ?

Comment: you mean ignore the time value associated with the date?!

Comment: yes sorry the time *

Comment: try: `=countif(index(int(A2:A5));">"&D4)`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are comparing to '09/04/2021', with no time specified, the time '00:00:00' is used.

When you change the function to:

```
=countIFS(A2:A4;">"&(D4+1))
```

You will compare if the datetime is largen than '10/04/2021 00:00:00', which should return the expected result.

Note: `D4+1`: when you add 1 to a date, it will return the next day.